# $fieldList not saving data of child table in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

When I save data in Post and Comment table without passing $fieldList 


`$this->Post->saveAll($this->request->data, array('deep' => true, 'validates'=>true)))`


It's working, but when I pass $fieldList 


`$this->Post->saveAll($this->request->data, array('fieldList' => $fieldList, 'deep' => true, 'validates'=>true)))`


data has been saved in parent table but in child table blank record entered.
How to save data in both table using fieldList

Comment: how did you set your $fieldlist variable?

Comment: $fieldList = array('title', .....) this array holds fields of Parent and child table

Comment: there is a typo mistake 'validates' should be 'validate'

Answer (score 1):

This is from the book:

```
$this->SomeModel->saveAll($data, array(
    'fieldList' => array(
        'SomeModel' => array('field_1'),
        'AssociatedModel' => array('field_2', 'field_3')
    )
));
```

So I think you are missing model name in your array.